# How can I unlock bootloader of LG Vortex (VS660)

Tags: bootloader, bootloader-lock

I'm trying to flash CyanogenMod to an old LG Vortex. I believe the first step is to unlock the bootloader. (I have successfully done this to a Nexus 7). I have `adb` and `fastboot` installed on LM17. Most guides (e.g. http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Template:Unlock_Bootloader) say that the process is:

```
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot oem unloack
```

However, the first command does *not* reboot to the bootloader. It just does a full boot to the phone's regular Android OS.

I have also tried booting to the bootloader using various key combinations (<kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>; I tried <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>, but that did a factory reset). I tried installing the QuickBoot app, which gives you a menu with Reboot/Bootloader/Recovery, but selecting Bootloader again just did a full boot to Android OS.

Note: phone is currently not rooted. I don't know if that is necessary for this phone, but I do know that I did not have to root when unlocked the bootloader on my Nexus 7.

Comment: Exactly the same problem in one device of mine, but I'm at least able to boot into Fastboot mode using key combinations. Do you not see the option to choose Recovery or Fastboot using key combinations?

Comment: @Firelord What key combinations are you using which would give the option Recovery or Fastboot?

Comment: It's a Chinese device and the combinations are "Vol. Up + Vol. Down + Power", I see two options: 1) Recovery Mode 2) Factory Mode. I Choose 1. and then I see three options from which I choose "Fastboot Mode" (Vol. Up selects the entry and Vol. Down executes the entry here).

Comment: That key combo did not work for me.